# How do you pass a value of a AutocompleteTextview to a string value in another Class or layout?

Tags: java, android

I wanted my AutocompleteTextView's value to be passed to the string at the Result value to make a query to search a column

Here's my main activity

```
Button Btn_AddToDB,Btn_Search;
AutoCompleteTextView actv;
ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter;
DBhandler dBhandler;
Cursor mItemCursor;
SQLiteDatabase db;
TextView Diesease, Definition, Medicine;
String word;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    dBhandler = new DBhandler(MainActivity.this);
    actv = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);

    ArrayAdapter<String> ard = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, str);
    actv.setAdapter(ard);

    actv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?>arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            word = String.valueOf(arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2));
        }
    });
    Btn_AddToDB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AddToDBbutton);
    Btn_Search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SearchButton);
    String word = actv.getText().toString();


    Btn_AddToDB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddDB.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(myintent);
        }
    });

    Btn_Search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {

        Intent myintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Result.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(myintent);
        }
    });
}
```

}

and here's my result :

SQLiteDatabase db;
    TextView Diesease, Definition, Medicine;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);

//  try {
    LayoutInflater auto = getLayoutInflater();
    View textsss = auto.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);

        Diesease = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Diesease_Textview);
        Definition= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Definition_Textview);
        AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)textsss.findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);
        String words = textView.getText().toString();

            Diesease.setText(words);

      /*
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT DEFINITION FROM " + Dictionary.Medictionary.Tablename + " WHERE " +Dictionary.Medictionary.Diesease+ " ='" +word+"'", null);
        if (res.moveToFirst())
        {
            Diesease.setText(words);
            String define = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("DEFINITION"));
            Definition.setText(define);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DATA NOT AVAILABLE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        res.close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),ex.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    */
}
```

I made the query comment so that I CAN TEST the value of my word is really being passed.But it returns blank.

Comment: Thanks bro I needed that one